# SWRevealViewController push segue create a new instance of the front destination controller. How can avoid it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm developing a simple iOS app and I'm using the famous library SWRevealViewController for the side menù.
I have the first view that is a Map with POI (front controller) and the side menù (rear controller) that contains the categories.
Now when I click on a category, it navigates ti the map controller but it is a new instance. I would the old instance to avoid to execute all the methods of the controller.

Does a way exist to navigate back to the old instance of the map controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with segues. You could do a programmatic approach and keep the view controller in memory and then present or push the view controller that is already in memory instead when you want to return to that screen. Rather than using `prepareForSegue` or `performSegue:withIdentifier` you would use `presentViewController:animated` or the navigationController's `pushViewController:animated:`. You can still instantiate it from the storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"MyIdentifier"];
```